# Правильно ли я расставила запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

... в течение нескольких минут в ушах звучат ещё веселые девические голоса, сдерживаемый смех, загадочный шепот.

Comment: Мадемуазель, дайте свой вариант.

Comment: в течение нескольких минут в ушах звучат ещё веселые  девические голоса, сдерживаемый смех, загадочный шепот.

Comment: Анастасия, в Вашем варианте запятые расставлены правильно

Comment: Лучше — «девичьи», меньше пафоса.

Comment: @shampar Осторожно, вы критикуете лауреата Пушкинской и Сталинской премий (http://az.lib.ru/w/weresaew_w_w/text_0010.shtml)

Comment: Это Анастасия начала. Я только вошёл, ничего не успел...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот оригинал:

**В ушах звучат еще веселые девические голоса, сдерживаемый смех, шепот...**

[ВИКЕНТИЙ ВЕРЕСАЕВ. БЕЗ ДОРОГИ. Повесть](http://az.lib.ru/w/weresaew_w_w/text_0010.shtml)